# Issue when python called from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am new to Javascript, python and php. I have a js program wherein I click a button, it calls a python program and receive the returned value to display on the screen. I am trying to avoid using Jquery and Json.

Below is the code of both Javascript and Python.

Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function cal()
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("do").innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "./pth.py", true);
  xhttp.send();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Submit" 
onClick="cal();" value="Test"/>
<div id="do">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "hello";
```

For the above code, the following is the output I am receiving (I see the entire python code rather than just hello)

```
#!/usr/bin/python print "hello";
```

Comment: Python is installed and executable as mentioned by you. The print part as well is in a new line. The output is displayed in one line.

Comment: Missed to mention that I am trying to execute the program on Windows platform and WAMP server

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable about python .Truth be told , I have never seen something like this ? There  is no server created in python in this case . You want to run a python code just by calling it through a http call ? I am not sure how that can happen . I think you should create a server in python , run it , and then  make it return whatever you want it to return

Answer (score 0):

To perform such actions you need to use [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) layer between your webserver and python scripts, because a webserver does not work with them directly. Usually the following backend stack is commonly used:

```
Scripts with business logic (python/perl/php) -> CGI layer (WSGI, uWSGI, etc..) -> Webserver (Apache, nginx, etc..)
```

So, you receive content of your script instead of it's output because it wasn't executed, just read like a text file.